# delete old logs using mysql and php only

Tags: mysql

I have a table called log where I store the everything that the user does. what I want to do, is to run a script after showing the last 100 results.

so basically, when the admin visits the log page, he/she will see the last 100 results. while showing the last 100 results I want to delete anything in the table log other than the last 100 results that I just showed. How can I do that? I only know of the basic code for deleting a table which is

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column = some_value
```

Comment: How do you determine which are the "last 100 results"?  Do you have a `TIMESTAMP` column containing the time of record creation?

Comment: no. but I can create one! how is that going to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a column containing the time of record creation:

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE created < (SELECT created FROM (
  SELECT created FROM log ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100, 1
) t)
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'log' for update in FROM clause

Comment: my query : 
`DELETE FROM userlog WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM userlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200, 1) `

which is based on your answer.

Comment: @shnisaka: See my revised answer, above.